# VQ-VAE uniform prior over the latent variables

Tags: probability, autoencoders, variational-bayes

[VQ-VAE](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2017/file/7a98af17e63a0ac09ce2e96d03992fbc-Paper.pdf) propose to

1. make the posterior categorical distribution $q(z|x)$ one-hot = defined as $1$ for the closest embedding $e$ in the codebook to the output of the encoder $z_e(x)$;
2. define a simple uniform prior over $z$ (the latent variables).

The authors claim that this obtains a KL divergence which is discrete and equal to $\log K$, where $K$ is the number of discrete latent embeddings.

If I understand correctly, that means that the range of the uniform prior over $z$ should be so that every embedding has a probability equal to $1/K$ to be the closest to the encoder output.

Am I correct?

If that's so, how should we initialize the embedding vectors? Should their weights be initialized to a uniform probability - $U[\min(z_e(x)), \max(z_e(x))] ; x\in X$?

Answer (score 0):

Several confusions here:

The VQ-VAE ELBO objective can be written as the KL divergence between the true and approximate posterior, as in [Rocca](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-variational-autoencoders-vaes-f70510919f73) which can be shown to be written as the expectation of the conditional likelihood - the KL divergence between the approximate posterior and the *prior*:

$$ argmax ELBO = argmin KL(q_x(z), p(z|x)) = $$
$$argmax(E_{z: q_x}(logp(x|z)) - KL(q_x(z),p(z)))$$

Now if the prior is uniform over the K possible values of z, and $q_x(z)$ is a one-hot distribution, it's clear that the KL divergence is a constant $logK$, so we're left with only maximizing $logp(x|z_q(x))$, which is exactly what's presented in [VQ-VAE](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2017/file/7a98af17e63a0ac09ce2e96d03992fbc-Paper.pdf).

Also, if we assume that p(x|z) is a Gaussian whose mean is a deterministic function of z (the decoder), and the covariance is $cI$, we can arrive at the familiar reconstruction MSE loss.

All this is unrelated to the initialization of the $e_k$ embedding values, which is also uniform but might as well be from another distribution.